# Python - Installing packages in Virtual Env

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying virtual env for the first time in python. I have Python 3.6 and Python 2.7 installed in my machine. I have installed all the necessary packages in Python 3.6. However, the code that I have seems to be compatible with Python 2.7. Hence I opted for Virtaul Env. But I could not access the packages that i need. I have went through the questions in stack overflow but nothing helped.
I have tried following steps:

- Created new project in pycharm
- used the interpreter as Python27
- in command prompt, I went to specific virtual env folder and tried
  pip  install package_name
- showing the error as below

  ```
  Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
    File "D:\Users\username\venv_name\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
      raise CodecRegistryError,\
                      ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  Current thread 0x0000d85c (most recent call first):
  ```

I need either to install packages in the venv or transfer already installed packages into venv.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to install packages to your virtual environment you need to add it first in PyCharm and use it as your interpreter.

You can add your venv by:

By going to Settings(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> in windows or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> in Macos)

Click the **⚙** icon next to project interpreter then choose add.
[image]

Browser for your virtual environment.
[image]

After that you can now install packages to your virtual env by clicking the ➕ icon.
[image]

---

Also you cannot just install packages in your virtual environment by going to its directory, you need to activate it first by:

Windows: `c:\path\to\your\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

Linux/Mac: `source path/to/your/venv/bin/activate`

Comment: When I attempt doing this, this warning me to close the python ("Close Program" error)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve your problem, since I don't use pycharm myself, but I can tell you what's causing it.

It seems that you are trying to run Python 2 code under Python 3. The `raise` expression that fails for you is valid under Python 2, but not under Python 3. Therefore the `SyntaxError`. So, you are probably using the source files from the virtualenv (see that `...\venv_name\...` path?), but executing them in Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: cd c:\Python37
run python3.exe (i renamed file)

I get the same error.
why does running Python3 in its native directory parse py files in virtualenv directory that is NOT activated (the virtualenv stuff I have setup is all done for Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

From another SO post, the issue is PYTHONPATH. Clear it, and you should be able to use 2 and 3.